# Como resolver o erro de conversão de expressão lambda do tipo ServiceLifetime net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, migrations

Estou iniciando um projeto bem simples com net core 2.2 e me confrontei com o seguinte erro: 
 ***Não é possível converter expressão lambda para o tipo "ServiceLifetime" porque ele não é um tipo delegado***

Arquivo startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<Menu>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Model:**

```
public class Menu
    {
        public int MenuID { get; set; }
        public string NmMenu {get; set;}
        public int MenuIdPai { get; set; }

    }
```

**Contexto:**

```
public class Ctx: DbContext
    {
        public Ctx(DbContextOptions<Ctx> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Menu> Menus { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>().ToTable("Menu");
        }
    }
```

**appsettings:**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Ctx;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando adicionar o contexto para sua e entidade `Menu` e não para a classe que realmente herda a `DbContext` que no caso é a `Ctx`. Mude seu código para

```
services.AddDbContext<Ctx>(options => 
                           options.UseSqlServer(
                               Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
                           ));
```

E desde já eu recomendaria você a utilizar uma instância real do SQL Server ao invés da `localdb`, isso já vai lhe poupar outras dores de cabeça mais a frente.